# Why $D_8$ is not primitive as a permutation group on the four vertices of a square?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why $D_8$ is not primitive as  a permutation group on the four vertices of a square?
By the way, here is the definition of primitive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? All you have to do is pick some blocks out of a set of four elements.

Comment: Yes, that is right. I am not sure what the blocks are.

Comment: Isn't $D_8$ like rotations?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just cannot figure out how that is not primitive. Isn't $D_8$ like rotations of the vertices each for angle 45? How can it not be primitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D_8$ is the group of rotations and reflections of the square. Two diagonally opposite points on the square make up a non-trivial block, proving that $D_8$ is not primitive.